# Why there are "editing rights"?I think u should not edit other people's writing, comment or maybe delete

Tags: discussion, editing

I do not think it is ethically right for someone to edit other person words. You may comment with what you want, or vote to delete if you find something wrong in what is written as a principle (racist/illegal/... etc), but not edit.

Execuse me if you have some extra time, u may use it to correct a scientific fact,answer a question,..or even have some fun; do not waste it in trying to impose ur opinion or writing style on other people. This is a discussion group, not a paper or a thesis that has to follow a certain format

By the way, it is also a well-known principle that u should prevent read ups & write downs to protect from Trojans. I suggest you should not give a higher privilege user the right to edit someone else's question or answer.

Comment: I think [this help article](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing) should answer your question. In short: editing is an important tool on this site that we use to create a high-quality Q&A pairs. If you are uncomfortable with other people editing your posts to (for example) improve its formatting and readability, you should not be making those posts  on this site.

Comment: @Discretelizard Make an answer?

Comment: @Raphael I think D.W. already covered everything I would want to add.

Comment: [How much personal style should be tolerated?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/how-much-personal-style-should-be-tolerated) seems related.

Answer (score 6):

This site works differently from others you might be used to.  A large part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions & answers, that will be useful not only to the poster but also to others in the future.  To support that goal, we encourage collaborative editing to improve questions and answers, so that they'll be more likely to be helpful to others in the future.  See [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576/160917) and https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing for more discussion.  I realize that this might be unfamiliar for those new to the site and might take some getting used to.

I will share some other comments, from looking through recent edits to your answers:  We expect people to write in grammatical English.  "Text-speak" like using "u" or "ur" or "r" (instead of "you" or "your" or "are") is discouraged here.  Please use complete sentences.  See [How to deal with user using txt spk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105497/160917).   Also, please don't use Latex for emphasis; *this* looks better than $this$ (i.e., use `*this*` not `$this$`).  Latex should be reserved for mathematics.  When you do post mathematics, I encourage you to use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.  We're looking for high-quality answers that will be useful to others.